# How to display the dropdown list using the states.map function?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, load, state

On the left image, we are fetching an API in the stateList function. The response that we are getting from the API in the loadstates function, we are storing that setstates variable.

on the right image, we are trying to display the values using states.map where states is the array, where we have stored the response data in array form.

[image]

Still we are getting the following error:

> TypeError: states.map is not a function

backend is in Node js and frontend is in react js

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code (or errors etc.). Copy the text to the question and format it with the code format tool.

Answer (score 0):

With React hooks, you don't mutate a state by interacting directly with it. So the `states.push` line is not a good practice, you would have to use only the `setStates` to change your state.

Since you are trying to create an array of objects, each object with `name` and `value`, and assuming `data` returned from the backend is an object, you can do the following:

```
stateList().then(data => {
  // Object.entries will transform your object into an array, with key value pairs
  const newState = Object.entries(data)
  
  setStates(newState)
})
```

Now you can map through your `states`, since it's an array.

The key takeway is: always mutate your state using the `setState` hook

Comment: I used the states.push for testing purposes only. But when I am mapping the states array, I am  getting the following error: "TypeError: states.map is not a function"

Comment: That's weird. One thing I notice, I would recommend you to use the `useEffect` hook to call `stateList`. So you can set the state right inside the `then` callback, like this:

```
const data = response.json()
const newState = Object.entries(data)
 
setStates(newState)
```